# HighCharts: Stacked bar chart with missing values

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a stacked bar chart for the results of a questionnaire. Problem is, the questions have different possible answers (most have 5 options, some only have "yes" or "no").

[A fiddle containing an example](http://jsfiddle.net/PeerBr/CWcxc/3/)

HighCharts wants me to list first each possible answer as a series (say answers 1-5), and then in each series the question:

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Answer1',
        data: [{
            name: 'Question 1',
            y: 7
        }, {
            name: 'Question 2',
            y: 5
        }]
    },
    {
        name: 'Answer 2',
        data: [{
            name: 'Question 1',
            y: 4
        },{
            name: 'Question 2',
            y: 3
        }]
    },{
        name: 'Answer 3',
        data: [{
            name: 'Question 1',
            y: 2
        },{
            name: 'Question 2 (a yes/no question does not have a 3rd value, but I cannot know that)',
            y: 0
        }]
    }]
```

I find this cumbersome and counter-intuitive, but I hope I'm just doing it wrong.

My problem: For some questions, the database returns less answers (because everybody gave the same answer). In this case, I cannot know that there could have been more than one answer, because some questions aren't "choose 1-5", but "1-3" or "yes/no". My backend won't inform me of NULLs. When I write the single answer I got to HighCharts, it would count as the first answer, which might be wrong.

Is there a way to "pivot" the bar chart specification? I would like to write the data like this: List questions, then list answers for each, with missing options no problem:

```
    series: [{
        name: 'How did you like us',
        data: [{
            name: 'Loved you - 5/5',
            y: 7
        }, {
            name: 'Below average - 2/5',
            y: 5
        }, {
            name: 'Not good - 1/5',
            y: 1
        }]
    },
    {
        name: 'Question 2: Will you come back?',
        data: [{
            name: 'yes',
            y: 4
        },{
            name: 'no',
            y: 3
        }]
    }]
```

It would be awesome if you could help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So how it should look like in output. Stacks which has 2/3 answers, instead of 5, should not me aligned as 5 option or I misunderstand

Answer (score -1):

One option would be to plot each of these as a separate chart, but make them the same size etc so that they line up beneath each other.